# How to navigate to the Current location in Google Maps using Android Framework?

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation

Can someone help me out in navigating from some location to my current location ?

Actually I was able to see my current location on my application. But if I see another location which is far away from my current location in the Google map then I want to navigate to the current location by clicking on a Button.

I have a Menu Item in my Options menu called My Location. On click this Item I want to navigate to my location from the other location that I am watching on Google Maps.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.mylocation:
                showCurrentLocation();
                return true;
            case R.id.menuItem1:
                showSatelliteView();
                return true;
            case R.id.menuItem2:
                showTrafficView();
                return true;
            case R.id.menuItem3:
                exitApplication();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void showCurrentLocation() {
       mapView.getController().animateTo(myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
    }
```

All the others are working fine. But when I click on My Location(id = mylocation) its giving exception on the Emulator.

It gives the following Error on my LogCat.

```
09-19 15:04:58.445: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at com.google.android.maps.MapController.setCenter(MapController.java:345)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at com.location.mylocation.MyLocation.showCurrentLocation(MyLocation.java:126)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at com.location.mylocation.MyLocation.onOptionsItemSelected(MyLocation.java:108)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2170)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:730)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:139)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:525)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6540)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
09-19 15:04:58.455: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you please post exception in stacktrace??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) to obtain coordinates of current location and pass them to `mapView.getController().animateTo(GeoPoint)`. Be aware when translating obtained `Location` to `GeoPoint`: the latitude and longitude obtained from `Location` should be multiplied by 1,e+6 (1 000 000).

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. I tried to do that. But its giving Runtime exception on the same line mapView.getController().animateTo(GeoPoint)

Comment: You can try `mapView.getController().setCenter(GeoPoint)` instead, it works for sure. If it will cause the same exception, then something in your code is wrong, you can post it in your question so we could help you. Stacktrace could be helpful too.

Comment: Please see the above code snippet. In the meanwhile I will try with setCeter. Thanks

Comment: Of course. You've got either `mapView` or `myLocationOverlay` not initialized, or your `myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation()` returns null. Debug or look though your full code to find which one is null. And learn to use LogCat, it says you the reason of the crash.

Comment: The good thing is I learnt how to debug an Android application. The bad thing is still I am not able to resolve this issue. And your are 100% correct that myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation() is null. Don't know how to get the Location object inside this showMyLocation() method.

Comment: Gracius, debugging is really helpful. I don't know if the `myLocationOverlay` is your custom implementation, but the reason of no result returning by that method could be that you are using emulator, don't you? There're no emulation of GPS AFAIK, so you need a real device to test your code.